# Markov chain and random iteration of functions

Tags: markov-chains

Could anyone give me some references for the convergence rate of Markov chain arising from the random iteration of Lipschitz functions which moves as follows:

$$ X_{n+1}= f_{\omega_n}(X_n)$$ where $f_1,\dots, f_s$ are Lipschitz functions (with Lipschitz constants $L_i$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{s} p_kL_k <1$ )on $\mathcal X$, a metric space with a metric $d$ it is complete and separable say. $\omega_0,\omega_1,\dots, \omega_n,\dots$ are i.i.d discrete random variable taking values in $\{1,2,\dots,s<\infty\}$. $p_k=\mathbb P(\omega_i=k)$.

I found Diaconis and Freedman's [Paper](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~cgates/PERSI/papers/iterate.pdf)
where they didn't talk about the finite number of functions though and convergence rate is exponential in Prohorov's metric.

While talking about the convergence rate of probability measures towards the invariant measure, we need to talk about some metric on the space of probability measures, which also a question, which metric to use in this case to find the rate. 
Thanks.

$\mu_n(A)=\mathbb P(X_n\in A)$ i.e $X_n\sim \mu_n$,

I am looking for some reference on the Wasserstein metric. 
Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is much more natural and convenient to metrize the weak topology on the space of measures with the transportation (aka Kantorovich-Rubinshtein, aka 1-Wasserstein) metric, especially in what concerns iterated function systems and various convergence issues in this context, see [Kaimanovich (1985)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=816292).

Let me denote by $d^*$ the transportation metric on the space of probability measures on a metric state space $(X,d)$. If $f$ is a map of $X$ to itself with the Lipschitz constant $L$, then obviously 
$$
d^*(f(\lambda),f(\mu))\le L d^*(\lambda,\mu) \;.
$$
Therefore if one has a family of such maps contracting on average, i.e., in the discrete case
$$
A := \sum p_i \log L_i < 0 \;,
$$
where $p_i$ are the weights of individual transformations $f_i$, and $L_i$ are their Lipschitz constants, then by the law of large numbers the time $n$ distribution of your Markov chain converges exponentially fast to its unique stationary distribution. Note that the right condition is $\sum p_i \log L_i<0$ rather than $\sum p_i L_i < 1$.

Moreover, for almost every Bernoulli sequence $f_{\omega_1},f_{\omega_2},\dots$ and any initial point $x\in X$ the sequence of iterations $f_{\omega_1} \dots f_{\omega_n}(x)$ exponentially fast converges to a point $z_{\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots}$ independent of $x$, and the distribution of these limit points coincides with the stationary distribution of the chain.

Comment: The metric $d^*$ is defined on the space of measures, therefore whenever I talk about $d^*$ its arguments are measures. What I have said is essentially contained in Theorem 5.1 from Diaconis-Freedman. However, the fact that they were not aware of the transportation metric and argued in terms of the quite unnatural Prokhorov metric instead made their arguments way much longer than necessary.

Comment: No - $f(\mu)$ is the image of the measure $\mu$ under the map $f$.

Comment: Yes - it's also called the push forward measure.

Comment: The Lipschitz constant of the iterated random product $f_{\omega_1} \dots f_{\omega_n}(x)$ will almost surely behave like $e^{nA}$, where $A=\sum p_i \log L_i$ is negative. All this is in a pretty detailed way explained in Diaconis and Freedman, one just has to apply it to the transportation metric instead of Prokhorov's one.

Comment: They look to me like ad hoc moment conditions - they are of course satisfied when one deals with finitely many transformations and are only needed to make sure everything remains under control even if the distribution is spread out.

Comment: Yes - they consider a measure $\mu$ on the space of maps $X$ and then look at two random variables (i.e., functions) defined on the probability space $(X,\mu)$. If $\mu$ is finitely supported, then the resulting random variables are also finitely supported, so that conditions (5.1) and (5.2) are trivially satisfied.

Comment: To begin with assume just that you have a sequence of transformations such that the product of their Lipschitz constants decays exponentially and look at what this sequence does to any measure on your space. Then average with respect to the distribution of these sequences.

Comment: @riemann Although RW's answer is quite complete for MO, let me mention that detailed elementary proofs are available in a paper of mine: https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.01655 (there is e.g. a small trick to avoid the Law of Large Numbers and still get the optimal convergence condition $\sum p_i \log L_i <0$.

Comment: @RW "Let me denote by $d^*$ the transportation metric on the space of probability measures on a metric state space $(X,d)$". Makes perfect sense if $X$ is bounded, but what if it isn't? I surmise the choice of the Prokhorov metric (with all related complications) was made exactly for that reason.

Comment: @fedia - Convergence in the transportation metric does imply weak convergence even when $X$ is not compact.

Comment: @riemann: this is not the place for extended discussion. The case of a finite number of maps is obtained by using a finite combination of Dirac masses for $\eta$. Lemma 3.2 is the main (rather trivial) point (proposition 3.9 to get the most general condition). $\otimes$ denotes the product of measures.

Comment: @fedja: it is not very difficult to manage unbounded spaces by considering measures with finite moment of order $q$ for some small enough $q$, but this is a point to indeed consider.